# WriteTextAsync not writing to file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have this piece of code:

```
string jsonPath = @"Model\Datamodel\UserData.json";

User userItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(user);
User.Add(userItem);

string content = user;
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(jsonPath);

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file,content);
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("DONE"));
```

The "Done" debug line is written in console but it does not write anything to the file.
I also don't get any errors. When I debug and look at Folder and file I see that they are correctly.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: As your answer says, you can't write there. You are probably getting an exception inside the task that is writing the file IO, but since you aren't checking the result, it *looks* like it succeeds, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to files in `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`, you need to use one of the other writeable locations available to you instead.  (e.g. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`)

If you need to access the content of the file that was shipped with the package, I would suggest copying it to the local folder, and using the copy for read/write access.

Comment: When I use the other folder I don't find my file? I get this error: A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: Well, no.  If you don't create the file then it won't exist, will it?  You should copy the file to the writeable storage area and then access it in the same way.